# Teams messaging extension Forbidden TeamsInfo.GetMemberAsync()

Tags: .net, .net-core, microsoft-teams

i build MS Teams messaging extension. Extension work fine, but when I want to fetch email of user, who use extension

```
TeamsInfo.GetMemberAsync(
            context,
            context.Activity.From.Id
        );
```

I get error

```
Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'
```

**Where is the problem?**

When I messaging with bot of this extension, all is good, but when I messaging with any other user, I get error.
I set permissions for bot to Read and ReadWrite Users, Members and Directories in Azure.

Comment: Could you please share which sample code and document you are referring for this?

Comment: I generate code by Visual Studio extension for Teams (Teams toolkit).

Comment: Could you please elaborate your issue in detail and please share screenshots or video of issue?

Comment: To solve issue I check if plugin is installed on chat, before send dynamic form from server to Teams. If not, server return AdaptiveCard with asking for install plugin (justInTimeInstaller).

Answer (score 0):

Adding answer from comment section for more visibility.

Check if plugin is installed on chat, before sending dynamic form server to Teams. If not, server return AdaptiveCard with asking to install plugin (justInTimeInstaller)